# parameter estimate matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, estimation, parameter-estimation

[image]

Im trying to find A

The parts in black are the information i was given , and the formula in red is what i used.

The numbers were randomly generated in the vector and matrix without constraint so i wasnt able to check my methodology trying to use any other parameter other than B(2) as they would be incorrect.

Was wondering if you would be able to check if i got my answer correct for A.

Multiply the Vector and Matrix together leading me to get:

(3.89)A = 6.78 - (8.21 * 6.56) - (6.51 * 4.78) - (4.67 * 7.56)

A = (-113.5006)/(3.89)

A = -29.18

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your working is correct.

$$(8.21)\cdot 6.56 + 6.51 \cdot4.78 + 3.89 \cdot\color{blue}{-29.177} + 7.56 \cdot 4.67 \approx 6.78$$